# Ajuste de anchura de columas con printf( )

Tags: c

Estoy intentado hacer un calendario gregoriano en C. Prácticamente ya lo tengo acabado (la parte funcional que consiste en indicar el calendario ya esta realizado) pero, me gustaría añadir el símbolo "|" tal como se muestra en la imagen que adjunto (uno abajo del otro). Pongo la parte del código que considero que esta haciendo referencia a esto (no consigo que estén alineadas). Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradezco.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
d = zeller(1, mes, year);
    for(i=1;i<d;i++){ //"puntos" hasta llegar al "primer lunes" de mes
        printf(" .  ");
        espacios += 1;
        
        if(espacios%5==1){
            printf("|");
        }
    }
      
    for(diasmes=1; diasmes<=totaldias; diasmes++){ //impresion de los días del mes
        if(diasmes<10){
            printf(" %d  ",diasmes);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d  ",diasmes);
        }
        
        if(espacios%7==5){
            printf("|");
        }
        
        if(espacios%7 == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
        espacios += 1;
    }
    
    ultimodiames = zeller(totaldias, mes, year);
    for(h=ultimodiames; h<7; h++){ //"puntos" desde ultimo día de mes, hasta final de semana
        printf(" .  ");
        
        espacios += 1;
        
    }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de la salida que produce tu código? Lo primero que he visto es que la parte inicial en la que imprime puntos hasta el primer lunes también debería tener en cuenta si atraviesa un fin de semana para pintar su barra. Por otro parte, para ver si entras en sábado puedes mirar si `espacios%7 ==5` en vez de todas las comparaciones. Y para imprimir el día puedes usar `%2d` para asegurarte de que ocupa dos posiciones, evitando así la comparación con 10.

Comment: He puesto una imagen de la salida que produce mi código. También he modificado el "if" que me comentaste, se ahorra mas código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes aquí:

```
        if(diasmes<10){
            printf(" %d  ",diasmes);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d  ",diasmes);
        }
```

aparte de que te puedes ahorrar el `if` si usas `%2d` como cadena de formato, estás metiendo dos espacios tras el día, y eso lo haces para *cualquiera que sea el día*, incluso si es viernes. pero los viernes deben tener un solo espacio ya que después irá la barra vertical. De hecho, podría aprovecharse aquí, al detectar que es viernes, para imprimir tras el día la barra vertical.

Por otro lado, la parte al inicio (o el fin) de mes, en la que rellenas con puntos, también debe tenerse en cuenta si el punto "cae de viernes", para poner la barra tras él.

Así pues, creo que el código que funcionaría sería el siguiente (aunque como no tengo el resto del programa no lo puedo probar, por lo que es posible que contenga errores):

```
    espacios = 1;
    d = zeller(1, mes, year);
    for (i=1;i<d;i++){ //"puntos" hasta llegar al "primer lunes" de mes
        if (espacios%7==5) { printf(" . | ");  } // Es viernes
        else { printf(" . "); }
        espacios += 1;        
    }
      
    for(diasmes=1; diasmes<=totaldias; diasmes++){ //impresion de los días del mes
        if (espacios%7==5) { printf("%2d | ", diasmes); }
        else { printf("%2d ", diasmes); }
        if(espacios%7 == 0) { printf("\n"); }
        espacios += 1;
    }
    
    ultimodiames = zeller(totaldias, mes, year);
    for(h=ultimodiames; h<7; h++){ //"puntos" desde ultimo día de mes, hasta final   
        if (espacios%7==5) { printf(" . | "); }  // Es viernes
        else { printf(" . "); }
        espacios += 1;        
    }
```

El código queda un poco repetitivo, ya que los tres bloques (puntos iniciales, días por el medio y puntos finales) tienen exactamente la misma estructura. Esto lo hace fácil de leer y de entender, pero en general la repetición de código no es buena.

Puede refactorizarse para usar un solo bucle que imprima todo y que determine si toca imprimir un punto o un día según el valor de un contador. Por ejemplo así:

```
  int inicio, seguir, contador=1, dia=1, totaldias=31;

  inicio = 7; // por ejemplo, el mes comienza en domingo 
              // Esto lo inicializaría tu función zeller(1, mes, year);
  seguir = 1;

  while (seguir) {
    if ((contador<inicio) || (contador >= totaldias + inicio)) {
      printf(" . ");
    } else {
      printf("%2d ", dia++);
    }
    if (contador%7 == 5) { printf("| "); }  // Es viernes
    else { printf(" "); }
    if (contador%7 == 0) { // Es domingo
      printf("\n"); 
      if (contador >= totaldias + inicio -1) { // Es el último domingo
        seguir = 0;
      }
    }
    contador++;
  }
```

El código anterior (para los valores con que he inicializado `inicio` para que comience en domingo y el número de días 31) mostraría lo siguiente:

```
 .   .   .   .   . |  .   1  
 2   3   4   5   6 |  7   8  
 9  10  11  12  13 | 14  15  
16  17  18  19  20 | 21  22  
23  24  25  26  27 | 28  29  
30  31   .   .   . |  .   .
```

Comment: Hice las modificaciones que has indicado y el código funciona perfectamente, ya lo tengo acabado. No pude poner el código completo porque me salía un mensaje que era demasiado largo. Gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: Considera entonces aceptar la respuesta para que la pregunta quede resuelta.

Comment: No sabía que hay esa opción en esta web. Ya está hecho, un saludo.